# jQueryUI modal dialog - dragging causes unexpected changes in position in Google Chrome

Tags: css, jquery-ui, google-chrome, webforms, jquery-dialog

Chrome   v. 26.0.1410.64

jQuery   v. 1.7.1

jQueryUI v. latest

web app is built using asp.net webforms

- What happens is that when the page is at it's top, dialog opens normally and everything works as intended. Dragging dialog causes no problems. If the page is scrolled down, when trying to drag dialog, dialog's **top** css property increases roughly by the value of the vertical scroll amount. This is happening only in Google Chrome.

This is the part of the function that opens the modal popup.

```
    var $dialog = $('<div id="dialogIframe" title="Some title"></div>')
    .html('<iframe id="jqueryIframe" style="border: 0px;" src="' + page + '"
    width="99%" height="99%"></iframe>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        buttons: dialog_buttons,
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $('#dialogIframe').remove();
        }
     });

     $dialog.dialog('open');
```

- I am working on someone else's code. I'm not sure what could cause this kind of behavior. **What could possibly cause this kind of behavior ?**

EDIT:
- when switching to jQuery version: 1.9.1 it works in Google chrome as expected, but the same problem now occurs in IE9 and FF latest (who were working properly with older jQ version)

EDIT 2:
- I have a feeling that this issue might be related to MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback page property in webforms, which I am by the way unable to disable or set to false in any conventional way: on aspx page, code-behind of the same page, master page, web.config, this is amazing

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue in chrome and solved it with

```
           open:function(){
            $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')
        },

    beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {
        $('body').removeClass('stop-scrolling')
    },
```

this works for me because my dialog is very small, but you could get in trouble when you have more content in your dialogue than you have space on your screen

the css class looks like

```
 .stop-scrolling {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

and prevents the body from scrolling

Comment: The problem is that this page is really long, so even if scroll is disabled while modal dialog is active, dialog still gets dispositioned the moment I try to drag it, because at the moment of activating it, I'm not necessarily at the top of the page. When I added newer version of jQuery (1.9.1) chrome wasn't an issue anymore, now firefox and IE showed same behavior as chrome did with old version.

Comment: did you try to set position:absolute in the iframe´s style attr. ?

Comment: yes, I have tried, it didn't make any difference. Thank you for trying to help.